# Syntax Question: @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Going from ASP.NET 2.0 (VB) to MVC 3 (C#), I'm very confused about the syntax being used for the View.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
```

Where did that m come from?  My only guess is that it represents the model that is being passed into the view.  I tried changing the m to c and it still works fine.

Is the part of the syntax that involves the "=>" more of a MVC, C#, or Razor element?

Comment: @NoProblemBabe, there is someone doing it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595947/asp-net-mvc-label-for

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Where did that `m` come from?

It's the parameter in a lambda expression.

> My only guess is that it represents the model that is being passed into the view. I tried changing the m to c and it still works fine.

That's because the name doesn't matter. It's just a parameter name, it doesn't actually refer to any existing variable.

> Is the part of the syntax that involves the "=>" more of a MVC, C#, or Razor element?

It's C#, but `LabelFor` uses what the compiler translates `m => m.UserName` into to extract what it needs to build up the label.

This is a very deep an intricate subject. I suggest that you find a book that you're comfortable with (e.g., C# in Depth is very good on this subject) to understand more. You want to read about lambda expressions and expression trees.

Comment: I don't he needs a book for it.

Answer (score 8):

It's a syntax trick that has been present since C# 3.0 (I think; maybe 3.5).

If you were to write this in code (and your Razor view does get translated to a C# code file before compiling, so it really *is* in code), there are two possible ways the compiler can compile it depending on the context.

If the method `LabelFor()` expects a delegate, it's compiled to an anonymous method. Alternatively, if the method expects an `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func>` type, an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) is constructed. This is what is happening in your case.

The reason for this convulted syntax is that the expression tree contains enough information, that (combined with Reflection) the `LabelFor()` method can extract the **actual property** to which you are referring. If you were to pass it simply as `LabelFor(Model.UserName)`, there wouldn't be enough information for the `LabelFor()` to do this. It would just get the value from the `UserName` property. But now it knows where it came from, and can use more Reflection to have a glance at the attributes of the property. Attributes such as `DisplayFormat`, `Required`, and others.

The `m` (or `c` or whatever) is actually your model. `LabelFor` is an extension method and it simply passes your model back to your Lambda expression, so that the whole expression tree trick can work. You could also write it like `LabelFor(x=>Model.UserName)`, but I don't think it would work (I haven't tried though, maybe it does).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explaining the reason behind the extended syntax.

Comment: Lambda expressions a syntax trick? They're a really important language feature!

Comment: Yes. It's a really important syntax trick. :) OK, well, I suppose a lot of language features could be called "syntax tricks". I use the term to mean "something that can be done without using the feature, except it gets a lot more tedious to write". For example, a lambda expression `x=>x*2` could be replaced with the more ancient `delegate(int x) { return x*2; }` syntax. Or, if it is used to construct a `Expression<T>`, then you could use the explicit `Expression` methods to build the tree. Of course, the code becomes tedious to the point where it's useless. But it still can be done.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin - Similarly, a `using(x) { ... }` is a "syntax trick", because you can replace it with `try...finally`. The same about `foreach` and `for` (because you can replace them with a `while`), etc.

Answer (score 3):

That's a Lambda Expression, [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

The deal is this: the m is a variable that receives the instance of the model in the given circunstance.
Inside the labelFor, it will call a compile-time created class, which has a method that does what you have passed as an argument to the LabelFor.

A lambda expression can be switched by a delegate, with the exact same results, excepting a minor, really minor performance boost, once.

The general idea is that you are passing a method to be execute somewhere in the LabelFor method.

ex:
the method:

```
public void Dummy(Action<string> action)
{
    if(iFeelLikeIt) {action("I feel Like it");}
}
```

Should be used as:

```
Dummy(msg => MessageBox.Show(msg));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is *Lambda Expression*. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):
A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or expression tree types.

All lambda expressions use the lambda operator =>, which is read as "goes to". The left side of the lambda operator specifies the input parameters (if any) and the right side holds the expression or statement block. The lambda expression x => x * x is read "x goes to x times x."

Answer (score 0):

The LabelFor is a Razor function that has knowledge of the Model internally. In other words, the model resides inside the LabelFor function logic. When you pass the lambda expression, you are passing an anonymous function to LabelFor so it knows what to do with its internal Model object to extract information.

Typically you would pass a Model as parameter and LabelFor would use internal logic to extract the information needed. But in this format, it is the opposite. The LabelFor knows the parameter internally (the Model) but it doesn't know what to do with it. You tell it what to do by passing the Lambda function.

When you run the code, you pass the Lambda expression as parameter to LabelFor. LabelFor, takes the lambda expression and passes it an internal copy of the Model object. The Lambda expression returns the UserName property of the Model object, and the LabelFor uses it to build your HTML code.